# Python - Infinite loop while batch-wise reading very large textfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, file

Alright, 
I have a large (8 GB+) txt file containing legacy data most likely from a mainframe b/c it's all fixed fields that must be parsed line by line & character by character. Reading the file line by line works fine on a small sample, but doesn't scale beyond a few hundred MB's.

Essentially, I want to read the txt file in batches, say five million lines per batch, and then process each batch line by line.

That's what I wrote in Python, but for some reason, the code below ends up in an infinite loop when tested on a smaller file. I am a bit baffled that the break actually never gets triggered and the snapshot gets overwritten all the time. Any idea how to fix that?

```
# Python 3.x 
def convert_txt_to_csv(path_to_txt, path_to_save_csv, column_names):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

    chunksize = 5000 # 5000000 - 5 million batches for the big file

    print("Add rows...")
    with open(path_to_txt, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as file:

        lines = True
        cnt = 0
        mil = 1

        while lines:

            lines = file.readlines(chunksize) # This guy should become False if there no more lines...
            if not lines:
                break # Double safety, if they're no more lines, escape the loop... 

            for line in lines:
                process_line(line.replace('\n', ''), df, cnt)
                cnt += 1

         # save snapshot after each batch 
         df.to_csv(path_to_snapshot_csv)
         print("Saved Snapshot: ", mil)
         mil +=1


    print("Process")
    df = process(df)
    print("Safe")
    df.to_csv(path_to_save_csv)
    print("Nr. of data: ", len(df.index))
```

Comment: Hi Marvin Hansen, can you provide a example sample of the input file and its matching output?

Comment: Thanks, just added an example. Just saying, conversion works on small samples. 

The actual problem I am trying to solve is to accelerate the conversion b/c doing line by line on 8GB takes forever and a day, thus batchwise...

Comment: How the data from the input matches the data in the output? For example, there's the string 'GREENE' in your input file but it is nowhere in your output file. There's a "CHINESE TIMES PUBLISHING CO" in your output but nowhere to be found in your input. And can your provide an example with more than one line so that we can see the variance in the input? Could you give an example with five records?

Comment: The input & putput samples don't match because they are from different rows

Comment: Can you give the output for the row you provide?

Comment: Why don't you just use `readline()` instead of `readlines()` ? (Notice the `s` at the end)

Comment: ChatterOne, good question. The thing is, I measured processed lines and doing batch wise seems to be faster. However, I have just read that using mmap might get some serious performance boost b/c it seems this one is really hard IO bound.

Comment: Well, it's faster because having everything in memory is faster, but if it's too big for that there's not much of an alternative. Maybe read and process a few lines (say 1000 lines) before actually writing them to disk, to reduce the I/O operations.

Comment: ChatterOne, it's solved. I update the question in a moment. Essentially three things happaned. Once, the snapshot line was incorrectly intended so it got called after each line instead after each batch. Then, the loop is actually correct but I was loading the wrong file wich was too big to handle. And finally, forget about mmap, I just created a ramdisk, and since then its all flying... Luckiliy my workstation has enough memory

Comment: Solved :-) Added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

The above code actually works, but the actual bug was that the snapshot line was incorrectly intended and got called after each line instead of after each batch thus creating the impression the loop would be stuck by re-creating the snapshot forever. Here a few optimizations I applied in the meantime:

1) For reasonably sized files w.o batching:

for line in file:  # Don't use readline...

```
        process_line(line)
```

2) For speeding up reading files:

Create a ramdisk and copy input file there.

3) For batching, the chunk parameter in readline is some kind of weird bytsize so, for example, 1500000 translates to 2995 lines read in a row.

With a ramdisk & batching, the processing is actually quite fast now. Thanks for all the valuable input & questions.